# How do I import Primefaces 6.0 source as maven project in Eclipse?

Tags: primefaces, m2e, eclipse-neon

I followed *Building From Source* https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/wiki/Building-From-Source instructions. Building the SNAPSHOT version project from command works well.

However, importing it into eclipse using the *Existing Maven Projects* wizard gives me a lot of errors in the *Problems* view. I fixed the lifecycle mappings by setting all to ignore.

I realized the generated source code in the *target/generated-sources/maven-jsf-plugin* directory but it was not picked up by the m2e plugins as a source folder automatically. So I included it into the eclipse build path manually. But then again, many compile errors show up in the generated code.

Does anybody use eclipse as IDE for primefaces development? How do you setup the eclipse project to develop primefaces?

Comment: I did it just like this. Works great for me

Comment: You give me hope :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The eclipse project uses Java Compiler compliance level **1.5** derived from the pom.xml maven-compiler-plugin settings. Setting the Java Compiler compliance level to **1.6** solved the issue for me.